# Porque me muestra valor al apretar la tabla

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente método donde obtengo un campo texto de la tabla.

```
function save(){
    $('#tableDespacho tr').on('click', function(){
        //var first = $(this).find('td:first').html();
        var area = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var fecha = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
        var cantidad = $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text();
        console.log(cantidad);
    });
}
```

A este método lo llamo con un botón:

```
<button type="button" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success done" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Recepcionar Item" data-original-title="Remove item"> 
    <i class='fa fa-check fa-lg '></i>
</button>
```

Aparte tengo un boton para editar la cantidad de la tabla.

```
$('#tableDespacho').editable({
    container: 'body',
    selector: 'td.Cantidad',
    title: 'Cantidad',

    validate: function(value) {
        if ($.trim(value) == '') {
            return 'Este campo es necesario';
        }
        var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(! regex.test(value)) {
            return 'Solo Numeros!';
        }
        //if ($(this).text() >= value) {
        //    return ' Excede cantidad';
        //}
    }
});
```

Al principio funciona bien puedo editar las cantidades y al presionar el boton me muestra la cantidad. Pero después editar y mostrar la cantidad si presiono la tabla me llama a la funcion `save`.

A que se debe esto?

tabla

```
<table id="tableDespacho" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th class="th-sm">CodPieza</th>
      <th class="th-sm">Cantidad</tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  <?php include_once('include/conexion.php');
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Despacho_DetalleEntreAreas ORDER BY Fecha DESC";
   $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
       if ($result) {
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
          if ($resultCheck >0) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
           <tr>
              <td>
               <?php echo $row['Desc_Area'] ?>
             </td>
             <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad <?php echo $text ?>" data-type="text">
               <?php echo $row['Cantidad'] ?>
             </td>

               <td>
               <button type="button" onclick="save()" id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success done" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Recepcionar Item" data-original-title="Remove item"> <i class='fa fa-check fa-lg mb-1 white-text'></i></button>
              </td>
               </tr>
            <?php } } } ?>
           </tbody> 
     </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque agregas el Listener `click` adentro de una función que se ejecuta con un `onclick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque en la funcion `save()` generas un `Listener`.
Ahora, ¿Qué es un listener?. Pues básicamente es una función que se ejecuta cada vez que cierto evento sucede, el evento que asociaste a ese listener fue `click` y se lo asociaste al selector `'#tableDespacho tr'`.

Dicho de otra forma, cada vez que haces un `click` en un elemento `tr` que es hijo del elemento con id `#tableDespacho` se ejecuta el código asociado, el cual es el siguiente:

```
// esta es la funcion que tu hiciste
function(){
    //var first = $(this).find('td:first').html();
    var area = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var fecha = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var cantidad = $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text();
    console.log(cantidad);
}
```

yo te propongo el siguiente cambio a tu código

```js
function save(btn){
    var area = $(btn).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var fecha = $(btn).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var cantidad = $(btn).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
    console.log(cantidad);
}
```

```css
td {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Área</th>
  <th>Fecha</th>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>area1</td>
  <td>fecha1</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td><button onclick="save(this)">Mostrar cantidad</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>area2</td>
  <td>fecha2</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td><button onclick="save(this)">Mostrar cantidad</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>area3</td>
  <td>fecha3</td>
  <td>25</td>
  <td><button onclick="save(this)">Mostrar cantidad</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Me selecciona la cantidad de la primera fila, puede ser por `first-child`?

Comment: exactamente, por casualidad ese boton está dentro de la tabla dentro una fila y es esa la que esperas obtener? si es así puedes usar `$(this).parent().find('td:eq(5)').text()`

Comment: cambie `$('#tableDespacho tr:first-child').find('td:eq(5)').text();` por `$(this).parent().find('td:eq(5)').text()` y no funciona :(

Comment: ese botón donde está? y como es que identificas de que fila seleccionar la cantidad? creo que me faltó un parent: `$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(5)').text()`

Comment: Al presionar el boton sacaba la `cantidad` de esa linea (yo para futuro hacer un update) pero tu codigo me saca la `cantidad` de la primera linea

Comment: prueba con esto `$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(5)').text()` o bien con esto `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text()`

Comment: @nada yo obtenia el dato asi `$(this).find('td:eq(5)').text();`

Comment: si pero es porque ese `this` correspondía al ambiente de la fila, pero ahora con el cambio que te sugerí el ambiente es del boton por lo que ahora hay que encontrar la fila que queremos, ahora en la primera aproximación la cantidad no la obtenias al presionar el boton, la obtenias al presionar la fila, te pregunto cual es la forma que quieres seguir, obtener el valor al presionar la fila o el boton?

Comment: Al presionar el boton porque voy hacer un update. Al presionar la fila yo edito la cantidad para luego presionar el boton y hacer un update

Comment: ok entonces te pregunto de nuevo, el boton está en una celda de la fila? podrías agregar una imagen de tu tabla para quedar claros o mejor aun podrías mostrar la sección html de la tabla, al menos una fila

Comment: Si esta dentro de una celda en esa fila, adjuntare una foto.

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando un snippet, ojo con los cambios porque ahora a la funcion `save` le mando como parametro `this`

Comment: @Muchas gracias por tu  tiempo funciona bien!.

Comment: de nada, como consejo la próxima vez intenta agregar un snippet (o jsfiddle o codepen o algo así) que simule tu problema de forma que sea mas fácil poder ayudarte

Comment: Una consulta entiendo que el post esta cerrado, pero me gustaria saber la forma de como poder disablear ese boton si en mi AJAX POST es success? Como obtengo ese boton de la fila para agregar un disable.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp

básicamente `<button disabled>boton</button>` agregas o eliminas el atributo disabled de un boton

Comment: Pero me disabled ese boton o el resto?

Answer (score 1):

Es obvio, estás creando el mismo evento en el botón y en el `<tr>` de la tabla.

Es decir, cuando le das al botón, estas creando una función que hace lo mismo pero para tu `<tr>` por eso si le picas por primera vez a la tabla no hará nada, pero si le das al botón y luego a la tabla ya creaste el evento.
Lo puedes solucionar así. Primero debes ponerle un id al botón, por ejemplo `id="btn"`

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#btn', function(e){
  //Esto para detener el handler nativo del botón y evitar que se propague la función a nodos más bajos
  e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
  //Primero buscamos la tabla y sus '<tr>'
  var tabla = $('#tableDespacho tr');
  //Despues empezamos a sacar la información justo como lo hiciste
  var first = tabla.find('td:first').html(),
      area = tabla.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
      fecha = tabla.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
      cantidad = tabla.find('td:eq(5)').text();
      console.log(cantidad);
    });
});
```

No tengo un ambiente de testing, pero espero que te funcione.

Saludos

Comment: Me selecciona la fila entera, yo quiero solo la cantidad de esa fila. Puede ser por el campo `id`

Comment: Pon la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: Listo quiero obtener la cantidad de la linea, no la fila entera de cantidades.